# Is there a way to display a class in python tkinter as a Frame, so other things can be added?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I want to have a tkinter window that displays both a cronometer and a sudoku. The cronometer is a class, so how can I add it to the window that displays the sudoku?

I already managed to get two separate windows, but I couldn't make one with both things.

```
def GUI4x4(dif):  #This function gets just called from other place

    # What I want is to be able to display this class
    # Cronometer in the main window that's created below

    class Cronometer(): 

        ...

        def __init__(self):
            self.crono=Tk()

            self.tiempo = StringVar()
            self.tiempo.set("00:00:00")

            self.label = Label(self.crono,textvariable=self.tiempo, bg="white")
            self.label.grid(column=0,row=0)
            self.label.configure(font=("Times 13 bold"))                
            self.btnI = Button(self.crono, bg="white", text="Start",command=self.iniciarT,font=("Times 11"))
            self.btnI.grid(pady=3,column=0,row=1)
            self.btnP = Button(self.crono, bg="white", text="Pause",command=self.pausarT,font=("Times 11"))
            self.btnP.grid(pady=3,column=0,row=2)
            self.btnR = Button(self.crono, bg="white", text="Restart",command=self.reiniciarT,font=("Times 11"))        
            self.btnR.grid(pady=3,column=0,row=3)


    GUI = Tk() # This creates the main window, and places
               # 34 buttons in it
    ...

    # Defining the Buttons
    btn00 = Button(GUI, text=Tablero[0][0], width=5, height=3, activebackground="lime")
    btn01 = Button(GUI, text=Tablero[0][1], width=5, height=3, activebackground="lime")
    btn02 = Button(GUI, text=Tablero[0][2], width=5, height=3, activebackground="lime")

    ...

    btn33 = Button(GUI, text=Tablero[3][3], width=5, height=3, activebackground="lime")


    #Placing the 34 buttons
    btn00.grid(row=0, column=0)
    btn01.grid(row=0, column=1)
    btn02.grid(row=0, column=2)
    ...
    btn33.grid(row=3, column=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to deal with this with tkinter is that each "widget" in the application is its own class based on the tkinter Frame widget, one class for the chrono, another for the sudoko game. There might even be a main app class.

Advantage of this method is that each widget frame can be created independently and then joined together later. These classes might also be split up in to separate code files.

A fairly simple example below

```
import tkinter as tk

class Chromometer(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.tiempo = tk.StringVar()
        self.tiempo.set("00:00:00")
        self.label = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.tiempo, bg="white")
        self.label.grid(column=0,row=0)

class Sudoko(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.label = tk.Label(self,text="Sudoko", bg="white")
        self.label.grid(column=0,row=0)


class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,**kw):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master=master,**kw)
        self.chrono = Chromometer(master=self)
        self.chrono.grid()
        self.sudoko = Sudoko(master=self)
        self.sudoko.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(master=root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Each class will have their own methods to perform the functionality needed by each. The chromo/chrono class will have a method to update the timer.